# android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, file-upload

I want to upload .pdf file using [alexbbb upload service library](https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service). But I keep getting `Error while uploading` in notification bar.

Logcat:

```
W/com.alexbbb.uploadservice.MultipartUploadTask﹕ Error in uploadId e28a7a1b-45af-42f1-a242-db69feba2d43 on attempt 1. Waiting 1s before next attempt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/0A09-1112:Contact n Tort.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

my `onActivityResult()`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        filePath = data.getData().getPath();
        File file = new File(filePath);
        filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        data.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
        choosenFile.setText(data.getStringExtra("filePath"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in choosing file",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

in `onUploadButtonClick()`

```
private void onUploadButtonClick() {
    final String serverUrlString = "http://XXXX/uploadNotes.php";
    if (filePath.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "filePath is null");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, filePath);
    }
    final String fileToUploadPath = filePath;
    final String paramNameString = "uploaded_file";

    String fileName[] = fileToUploadPath.split("/");

    final MultipartUploadRequest request =
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), serverUrlString);

    request.addFileToUpload(fileToUploadPath, paramNameString,
            fileName[fileName.length-1]+".pdf", ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

// code.....
}
```

I already allow permission to read and write to external storage in `AndroidManifest` so probably the problem is I use incorrect `filePath` to upload.

What should I do to make it works?

UPDATE:

I use `getAbsolutePath()`, `getAbsoluteFile()`, `getCanonicalPath()`, `getCanonicalFile()`, and `getPath()`, all return `/document/0A09-1112:Contact n Tort.pdf`

Filename is `Contact n Tort.pdf` (have no idea what is 0A09-1112: is) and located in SD card/document

Comment: The error says it all: '(No such file or directory)'. You're either looking in the wrong place or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I picked the file first before upload. So the file does exist.

Comment: Why don't you try debugging your application, looking at the actual file path it's using, and then  double-checking that it's the correct path for the file.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: because it is not located on SD .... check the full `data.getData()` ... i'm pretty sure that it starts from `content` not `file` ... asked many times

Comment: I did google the problem before and tried many solutions before post the question. no luck. @Selvin